# How to reward user after installing app form rewarded video - android

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am using rewarded video service from Admob un my android application and the users are rewarded when the video ends.

I want to reward users only after the user installed the app from the video. How can i do that?

Comment: Provide a link of the app below the video ad.@Stefan

Comment: I still want to monetize the video normally. I'm asking if is any Listener for play store to check If that app has been installed.

Comment: I think it is impossible to clearly say when other application is installed.
The only way I think of is listening for your app close after they clicked on ad, wait for their comeback and reward user after some time (time required to install app, tell the user they have to install app, maybe they will not notice how to cheat this system).

Comment: It should work but, I'm thinking at using an push notification listener to detect when the app is going to be installed. Or to detect the installed package names, but I can't get the pakage name variable from the ad network.

Answer (score 0):

Implement RewardedVideoAdListener and override its methods

```
@Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {

   // here in this method you have to reward the user

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use deferred deeplinks. If you are using branch.io or appsflyer for the same. Deferred deeplinks are the links that can deliver you the customized url once you install the app via ad campaign. You can parse the deeplink and then do the needful.